# Using one sqlconnection/sqlcommand through 2 DB-bound methods

Tags: c#

I have a class with a method which gets data from a database through a SELECT stored proc. This method uses a `SqlDbReader` by returning `ExecuteReader()` on a `SqlCommand`.

The connection and everything is made in this method, with fields (such as connection string) set as class level fields.

I now need to populate an array based on the results of this query (so the columns of each row will go into the array with its own index).

However, this query will not select all of the data from one table which is involved. I can write the queries to get what I need, but how can I use one connection throughout the class? If I instantiate the connection object and call `Open()` in the constructor, I get an exception at runtime.

I'm hoping for something like this:

```
// At class level:
sqlconn.Open();
// sqlcommand set up


Method()
{
// Fire stored proc
// Insert results in a collection
}

Method2()
{
// Pass same collection in (use same one),
// Add new row columns into same collection
}
```

How can I do this with strict performance in mind?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to pass your connection object around:

```
// At class level: sqlConn.Open(); // sqlcommand set up

Method(sqlConn) { // Fire stored proc // Insert results in a collection }

Method2(sqlConn);
sqlConn.Close();
```

The basic premise is to open as late as you can, and close as early as possible. You can even write another method that opens the connection, calls all the methods that will use it, and then closes it.

Comment: Cool. I'll give that a go. The method you describe basically does everything but calls methods which fire stored procs, am I right? For technical reasons with an API, I can't use parameters so I won't be able to specify which method(s) to fire/not fire.